# spatie/calendar-link, not supported calendar message.ics

Tags: laravel, icalendar, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to send a calendar invitation in Laravel using [spatie/calendar-links](https://github.com/spatie/calendar-links) package but, in outlook, I get an attachment named "not supported calendar message.ics".

Here's how I generate the file contents and save it in a folder:

```
$ics = Link::create('Viaggio', $from, $to)
      ->description('Viaggio Da '.$data['travel']['departure'].', A '.$data['travel']['destination'])
      ->address($data['travel']['departure']);
      
      \Storage::disk('uploads')->put('invitation.ics', $ics->ics());
      $data['ics'] = $ics->ics();
```

Then i send the email like this:

```
Mail::send('view.email', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
     
     $message->from('email@email.coom', 'blablabla');  
     $message->subject('blablabla');
     $message->attachData($data['ics'], 'uploads/invitation.ics', [
           'mime' => 'text/calendar;charset=UTF-8;method=REQUEST',
        ]);
     $message->to($data['driver']['notifymail'], $data['driver']['businessname']);
  });
```

Contents of the .ics file:

```
data:text/calendar;charset=utf8,BEGIN:VCALENDAR%0d%0aVERSION:2.0%0d%0aBEGIN:VEVENT%0d%0aUID:ea22b2a397b12a7b2f629720cd46d84e%0d%0aSUMMARY:Viaggio%0d%0aDTSTART;TZID=UTC:20190323T102643%0d%0aDTEND;TZID=UTC:20190323T122643%0d%0aDESCRIPTION:Viaggio Da mxp\, A Via rossi 13\, Milano%0d%0aLOCATION:mxp%0d%0aEND:VEVENT%0d%0aEND:VCALENDAR
```

The email itself is fine, the only problem is the ics file: am i missing something? Am i not using the package the right way?

Comment: The only way I could figure out how to attach is do it direclty on the $message->to.  So try this: $message->to($data['driver']['notifymail'], $data['driver']['businessname'])->attachData($data['ics'], 'invitation.ics', [
           'mime' => 'data:text; charset=UTF-8;method=REQUEST',
        ]);;  Also I changed the 'mime' to data:text.  again worked for me hopefully it'll do the same for you.

Comment: actually sorry I found my working code.  try this: )->attach($data['ics'], ['as' => 'reminder.ics', 'mime' => 'data:text charset=utf8'])